# Generating random numbers in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic dice roller. When i run this program in Codeskulptor, it throws an error on the randint function. Can I not set the range for it using `raw_input` plugged into variables? Is there a different function I should use?

```
"""Program to roll random numbers within the ranges set."""

import random
sides_of_die=raw_input("Enter how many sides your die has: ")
number_of_dice=raw_input("Enter number of dice you have: ")
total=sides_of_die*number_of_dice
rollinput=raw_input("Would you like to roll now?")
rollinputcap=rollinput.upper()
if rollinputcap =="Y":
    print random.randint(number_of_dice,total)
else:
    print "What do you want then?"
```

Comment: The distribution of multiple dice is not the same as the the distribution of sides*number, you need to get a random number for each die and add them if you want to be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the `raw_input()` problem pointed out by the others, @Mark Ransom's comment is important: the sum of dice value eventually follows normal distribution. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Probability

Your:

```
if rollinputcap =="Y":
    print random.randint(number_of_dice,total)
```

should be changed to

```
if rollinputcap =="Y":
    sum_dice=[]
    for i in range(number_of_dice):
        sum_dice.append(random.randint(1, sides_of_dice))
    print sum(sum_dice)
```

Comment: You can shorten the summation considerably with a generator expression: `sum(random.randint(1, sides_of_die) for n in range(number_of_dice))`

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input()` returns a string, not an integer. To convert it to an integer type, use [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
sides_of_die = int(raw_input("Enter how many sides your die has: "))
number_of_dice = int(raw_input("Enter number of dice you have: "))
```

What's happening in your code is, you may input `"6"` and `"2"`, so when you do `total = sides_of_die * number_of_dice`, you're getting a `TypeError`

Answer (score 2):

This is just because `raw_input` returns a string, not a number, while `randint` accept two numbers as arguments

so you should do

```
total = int(raw_input(..))
```

Point is, this is not always secure. Exceptions are very likely to be thrown, so you might want to use a `try` block; but for the time being, I think it's okay (I'm assuming you're just learning Python).

Another thing, which is rather important:

Look at the exception! If you'd read it, you would have known exactly what the problem was.